# How to use no_argument in getopt_long in?

Tags: c, getopt-long

I am trying to use getopt_long for my code. The optional_argument and required_argument options are working as desired but the no_Argument option is not working properly. This is how I am coding it.

```
struct option long_option[] = 
{
  {"auto",required_argument,0,'a'},
  {"help",no_argument,0,'h'},
  {"list",no_argument,0,'l'},
  {0,0,0,0}
};
```

Now if I compile and try:

```
./a.out --help
```

--> shows all the help contents

```
./a.out --help 1234
```

--> still shows all the help contents. It should prompt an error that argument not required??

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not considered an error. `getopt_long` interprets `1234` as a program argument.

It's clearer in this example:

```
rm -r -f dir1/ dir2/
```

Here `-r` and `-f` are options, and both `dir1/` and `dir2/` are program arguments.
Note that if you execute `rm file1.txt -f`, it will try to delete a file named "`-f`".

Comment: "*... it will try to delete a file named -f.*". This actully depends on the implementation of `rm`. In fact it doesn't on recent Linux.

Comment: OK i get it but then what is the use of the no_argument option in the structure? For this thing to work will I have to use if/else loop in the "case 'h'" inside the switch loop to check if there is any program argument after --help/--list?